# How to pass express variable to .jade email template file

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug

I mam nodemailer [Here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) and my email template [Here](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates).

```
exports.newRegistration = function(user, req){

  var sendPwdReminder = transporter.templateSender(new EmailTemplate(templateDir));

        // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    var formattedUrl = url.format({
        protocol: req.protocol,
        host: req.get('host')
    });
    // use template based sender to send a message
    sendPwdReminder({
        from: '"mydomain.com " <donotreply@mydomain.com>', // sender address
        to: user.Email,
        // EmailTemplate renders html and text but no subject so we need to
        // set it manually either here or in the defaults section of templateSender()
        subject: 'New Account Registration ✔'
    }, {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password,
        redirectUrl: url.parse(formattedUrl + '/signup/confirm/' + user.Username + '/' + user.Token, true)
    }, function(err, info){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error sending email', err);
        }else{
            console.log('Password reminder sent');
        }
    });
}
```

I have my 3 jade files in my template folder as suggested in the doc. `html.jade` , `text.jade` , `subject.jade` .

My code is working and sending my template to my destination email. However, i am not able to send some variables to my template . Example username, name , email etc. i want to be able to add like

```
h1 Welcome #{username}
```

Please how do i pass the variables to the jade template ? I couldn't find a similar example yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rework this a slightly. If you call `template.render()` first you should be able to get the HTML or text of the email, which you can pass on to nodemailer:

```
var template = new EmailTemplate(templateDir);
template.render({"username": user.username}, function(err, result) {
    var mailOptions = {};
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        // Handle error, etc
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In his apparently the only error code it is the way in which you are seeking this variable.

I did exactly what you did and instead of Jade use EJS. Then pull the variable placing <%=variable%> instead of {{variable}}